# How do you click a class button in WebKitBrowser?

Tags: c#, button, webkit, click

I have this code for a class button:

```
<a class="bid-button-link button-big" href="/bid.php?scheck=fb7520ee7496e528b90117fa46dcb2ad&id=4042" title="4042"></a>
```

I could normally do this with a regular browser:

```
HtmlElementCollection elc = this.webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a");  
foreach (HtmlElement el in elc)  
{  
    if (el.GetAttribute("class") == "bid-button-link button-big") 
    {  
        el.InvokeMember("click");  
    }  
}
```

But since I am using a `WebKitBrowser`, I can't do that.
I make a can get the button with this code:

```
foreach (Node bidButton in webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a"))
{
    if (((Element)bidButton).GetAttribute("class") == "bid-button-link button-big")
    {
        //Code to click the button
    }
}
```

But I don't have any way to click the button, because `WebKitBrowser` does not have an option to `.InvokeMember("Click")`

Is there any way to click the button even though it is a `Class` `Button`?

Answer (score 3):

As you know, In the normal framework of Visual C# (WebBrowser) you can do something like this:

```
WebBrowser.Document.GetElementById("the ID").click()
```

But in WebKitBrowser the click() method is not defined, you can also emulate the JavaScript code of the click method with this function:

```
WebBrowser.StringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("Document.GetElementById('the ID').click();")
```

Hope this help you!

**Edited:**

change your code to this:

```
foreach (Node bidButton in webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a"))
{
    if (((Element)bidButton).GetAttribute("class") == "bid-button-link button-big")
    {
        bidButton.SetElement("id","Bidbutton")
        WebBrowser.StringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("Document.GetElementById('BidButton').click();")
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Dylam! Please check [my question about WebKit-sharp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35576038/html-ui-using-webkit). I'm sure you can suggest something. Regards!

Answer (score 0):

The suggestions above worked for me, but only after I first called focus(), if you're having trouble, try that.

Eg:

```
webKitBrowser.StringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("document.getElementsByTagName('input')[7].focus();") 

webKitBrowser.StringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("document.getElementsByTagName('input')[7].click();")
```

Answer (score -1):

How about bidButton.click()? Don't know which webkit bindings you are using, but click function is available in most of the implements.

Comment: In another answer to my question that didn't even help at all, you yourself stated that you don't know anything about .NET, but now you are trying to answer .NET questions. You should only answer questions that you can answer. And no, that does not work, or I would have done that...

Comment: Perhaps you can add details about which binding you are using. Just using webkit does not tell us which binding you are using. If you give complete information, I cross check to see if its supported in your binding or not.

Comment: What I mean by webkit binding is library you are using? Is it webkit.net, open webkit sharp etc? Each has its own flavour and details do change a lot. I do use webkit a lot on multiple platform and do lot of operations to similar. And yes, I was trying to help, but without details, it becomes hard

Comment: I'm pretty sure I'm using WebKit.NET.

Comment: It looks like all these libraries use a tlib file provided by apple for implementing windows version of safari. For some reason, many dom methods are not exposed in domhtml.idl.